# Difference between Entity attribute value model and data warehousing

Tags: database, relational-database, data-warehouse

i am reading about the "entity attribute value model" which sort of reminds me of an star-schema which you use in data warehousing.

One table has all the facts (even if you mix apples,bananas e.g. date of farming, weight, price, color,type,name) and a bunch of tables holding the details (e.g. infected_with _banana_virus_type, apple_specific_acid_level)

I do this in both aproaches, so I can't see a difference in these to words?

Please enlighten me. CHEERS

Answer (score 4):

In **all** approaches you have entities, attributes and values.  Everything reduces to this logically.  Since **everything** has entities, attributes and values, you can always claim that everything is the same.   All data structures are -- from that point of view -- identical.

Please draw a diagram of a star schema.  With a fact (say web site GET requests) and some dimensions like Time, IP Address, Requested Resource Path, and session User.

Actually draw the actual diagram, please.  Don't read the words, look at the picture of five tables.

After drawing that picture, draw a single EAV table.

Actually draw the picture with entity, attribute and value columns.  Don't read the words.  Look at the picture of one table.

Okay?

Now write down all the differences between the two pictures.  Number of tables. Number of columns.  Data types of each column.  All the differences.

We're not done.

Write a SQL query to count GET requests by day of the week for a given user using the star schema.  Actually write the SQL.   It's a three-table join.  With a GROUP BY and a WHERE

Try and write a SQL query to count GET requests by day of week for the EAV table.

Okay?

Now write down all the differences  between the two queries.  Complexity of the SQL, for example.  Performance of the SQL.  Time required to write the SQL.

Now you know the differences.

Comment: +1 I've no idea either of the differences, but that's a great answer.

Comment: +100 Thanks. Okay I did what you said, if I try and keep the main EAV-table minimal i see a lot of differance. But as soon as you pull some general attributes into the EAV-main-table it becomes very star-like.

Comment: "general attributes into the EAV-main-table"?  What does that mean?  You can only have three attributes in an EAV table: Entity Name, Attribute Name, and Value.  What are you talking about?

Comment: Okay I am slowly catching on. EAV really means all attributes are mapped via metadata and the're no exclicit column names for attributes (This is my understanding of EAV). While reading I heard if attributes get named in application logic they should have an exspisit column. Because I don't want one sparse table I pull these sparse attributes into separate tables. So the main table has a bunsh of often 80% used attributes.  Is this sill some hybrid-EAV or is this a classical star?

Comment: @hans.g: There is no "hybrid-EAV".  EAV is a minimalist kind of abstraction.  Once you move away from it you're doing ordinary relational database design.  Then the "star-like" vs. "non-star-like" is all a matter of taste and judgement.  But EAV is a specific, narrow, non-relational database model.

Comment: @S.Lott okay I get that. Thanks alot. ps. i'm reading this at the moment, thy're all talking about hybrid: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481672/is-eav-hybrid-a-bad-database-design-choice

Comment: @hans.g: As I said, there's no such thing as an EAV-hybird.  That question is just a relational database.  EAV, like binary number, has a definition.  EAV-Hybrid is like "number" and can mean anything.  In the case of that question, it seems to mean almost nothing.