# Many to many relationship with different data types

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am trying to create a Database for different types of events. Each event has arbitrary, user created, properties of different types. For example "number of guests", "special song to play", "time the clown arrives". Not every event has a clown but one user could still have different events with a clown. My basic concept is

```
propID | name | type
------ | ---- | -----
    1  |#guest| number
    2  |clown | time
```

and another table with every event with a unique eventID. The Problem is that a simple approach like

```
eventID | propID | value
------  | ------ | -----
     1  |    1   |  20
     1  |    2   |  10:00
```

does not really work because of the different DataTypes.

Now I thought about some possible solutions but I don't really know which one is best, or if there is an even better solution?

## 1.

I store all values as strings and use the datatype in the property table. I think this is called EAV and is not considered good practice.

## 2.

There are only a limited amount of meaningful datatypes, which could lead to a table like this:

```
eventID | propID | stringVal  | timeVal | numberVal
------  | ------ | ---------  | ------- | --------
     1  |    1   |   null     |  null   |    20
     1  |    2   |   null     |  10:00  |   null
```

## 3.

Use the possible datatypes for multiple tables like:

```
        propDateEvent                   propNumberEvent
--------------------------          --------------------------
eventID | propId | value            eventID | propId | value 
--------|--------|--------          --------|--------|--------
    1   |    2   |  10:00              1    |    1   |  20
```

Somehow I think every solution has its ups and downs. #1 feels like the simplest but least robust. #3 seems like the cleanest solution, but pretty complicated if I wanted to add e.g. a priority for the properties per event.

Comment: have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481672/is-eav-hybrid-a-bad-database-design-choice) and [this](https://sqlblog.org/2009/11/19/what-is-so-bad-about-eav-anyway). Imho, first case is better because of its flexibility, if you dont have limited type of datatypes.

Answer (score 0):

All the options you propose are variations on entity/attribute/value or EAV. The basic concept is that you store entities (in your case events), their attributes (#guest, clown), and the values of those attributes as rows, not columns.

There are lots of EAV questions on Stack Overflow, discussing the benefits and drawbacks.

Your 3 options provide different ways of storing the data - but you don't address the ways in which you want to retrieve that data, or verify the data you're about to store. This is the biggest problem with EAV.

How will you enforce the rule that all events must have "#guests" as a mandatory field (for instance)? How will you find all events that have at least 20 guest, and no clown booke? How will you show a list of events between 2 dates, ordered by date, and number of guests?

If those requirements don't matter to you, EAV is fine. If they do, consider using a document to store this user-defined data (JSON or XML). MySQL can query those documents natively, you can enforce business logic much more easily, and you won't have to write horribly convoluted queries for even the simplest business cases.